# Android - Can I reuse the Contact Picker with a different provider?

Tags: android

I would like to reuse the native Contact Picker of a User's device by doing the following:

```
public void doLaunchContactPicker(View view) {
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

            // Made up code that I am sure doesn't exist
            contactPickerIntent.putExtra("MyRemote3rdPartyContactList", remoteContacts)

    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
}
```

However, instead of looking at their contacts that are on the device, I would like to re-configure the Contact UI to point at a Custom Contact Provider that I populate via webservice call in my app.

How would I go about doing this if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically not possible: the default Contact picker doesn't have any code to let you feed it a different data source.

If you really want you can [pop open the source](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/src/com/android/contacts/activities/ContactSelectionActivity.java) and poke at it: maybe you can reuse it for your purposes.